# Android: set automatic update for app

Tags: android, auto-update

I downloaded the News Republic app and I noticed that in my Android Market account this app is marked for automatic updating.

Does anyone know how I can automatically enable this feature for users who download my application? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An application is automatically updated when you republish another apk with a higher version (as specified in AndroidManifest.xml). If you wish to push other resources without republishing, you will have to implement download/install/settings/ yourself.